# changevalue listener spinner javafx

Tags: javafx

Hello I would like refresh a Label every key in a spinner.
I have this following code :

```
spinner.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!"".equals(newValue)) {
            System.out.println("spiinerrrr");
        } 
    });
```

OK this code is good when I clicked in the arrow of the spinner, but when I clicked in the input field of spinner and I write a number, the

```
System.out.println("spiinerrrr");
```

is not executed.

Why ? I don't find a change value listener for the component spinner while for the textfield the code following is good when I write in the textfield :

```
textfield.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
        if (!"".equals(newValue)) {
            System.out.println("textfield");
        } 
    });
```

Comment: So, would you like to refresh the text of a `Label` every time the spinner value has been changed?

Comment: Yes, in fact, to replace the `System.out.println("spinner")`, I have `myLabel.setText(newValue)`, but when I write in my spinner, not working, working just when i clicked in arrow of spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener to the `textProperty` of the `Spinner`:

```
spinner.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (!"".equals(newValue)) {
            System.out.println("spiinerrrr");
        } 
    });
```

Otherwise you have to press enter before the `valueProperty` is updated.

if you want to update the `valueProperty` also when the focus is lost (without having to press enter), add an additional listener to the `focusedProperty`:

```
    spinner.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == false) {
            this.increment(0); 
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, the code is not executed becase the `valueProperty` is not changing.

You have to press <kbd>enter</kbd> to apply the text inside the editor and have the `valueProperty` changed.

From the [doc of editableProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Spinner.html#editableProperty):

> The editable property is used to specify whether user input is able to
>   be typed into the Spinner editor. If editable is true, user input will
>   be received once the user types and presses the Enter key. At this
>   point the input is passed to the SpinnerValueFactory converter
>   StringConverter.fromString(String) method. The returned value from
>   this call (of type T) is then sent to the
>   SpinnerValueFactory.setValue(Object) method. If the value is valid, it
>   will remain as the value. If it is invalid, the value factory will
>   need to react accordingly and back out this change.

If you need a `Spinner` that reacts immediatly to the change of the text in its editor, you can do it somehow like this:

```
Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(0, 500, 0);
spinner.setEditable(true);
spinner.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldval, newval) -> {

    SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> valueFactory = spinner.getValueFactory();
    if (valueFactory != null) {
        StringConverter<Integer> converter = valueFactory.getConverter();
        if (converter != null) {
            try {
                Integer value = converter.fromString(newval);
                if (value != null)
                    valueFactory.setValue(value);
                else
                    valueFactory.setValue(0);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                spinner.getEditor().setText(converter.toString(valueFactory.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Note:** your needs perfectly match to use a binding rather than listeners:

```
label.textProperty().bind(spinner.valueProperty().asString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getEditor()` method to access `TextField` of spinner and then add listener:

```
Spinner<String> sp = new Spinner<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"));
sp.setEditable(true);
sp.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) -> {
    System.out.println(newValue);
});
```

If you need to know, when user entered new value then:

```
sp.getEditor().setOnAction(e -> {
    System.out.println(sp.getEditor().getText());
});
```